# Should I lock all files to avoid merge issue when I using SVN?

Tags: file, svn, merge, locking

I want to use SVN to control my own file(xml and binary files), should I lock all the files to avoid merge issue?

Our team want to use SVN to manage our project files, everyone in our team can edit the project files( like code files managed by svn), and our project files include xml and binary files. So Should I lock the project files while others can not commit it until I finished my edit and commit it?

Is it reasonable to lock all files to avoid all merge issues?

Comment: Please add some more information on what you're trying to achieve and what problems you run into. Are you the only person working with your SVN repo? What kind of merge issues do you see?

Comment: @Friedrich Thank you so much for you reply. I add more details. Actually our team want to lock all files to avoid any merge issues. I don't know it is reasonable to lock all the files. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's generally not reasonable to lock all files to avoid merge issues.

The canonical resource for Subversion, the Red Bean Book, features a [chapter on locking](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html). The example there says almost everything.

To summarize a few key points:

- generally, there's no need to lock textual data as it can be merged
- locking binary data can be helpful as there's usually no way to merge changes to binary data

For textual data, locking only shifts the burden of merging from one developer to another. The essential complexity of performing a merge remains the same.

So far, we've been talking about locking a single file. Locking *everything* will make sure that the right file is locked but all the others are as well. Before version control systems, some shops had all the code on a network share and only the developer in possession of a physical token was allowed to modify it. Locking everything degrades Subversion to such a system.

In my own experience with Subversion (about 15 years in total), I have encountered few situations where whole repo locks were applied. Some of them were *spring cleaning* operations where structural changes were made. And sometimes the locks were motivated by high business value rather than technical reasons, e.g. when creating a release for a customer. I've encountered just as many situations where locks would have been helpful but instead somebody sent a mail to *all* asking them not to commit any changes.

In closing, I've never seen something go really wrong because somebody locked or failed to lock something.